# Basic Express Server Comment On Top

Tags: node.js, server, comments

I am learning node basics. When i run it, there is a comment at the top in browser. What is it for? I mean these: // 20210327050654

```
// 20210327050654
// http://localhost:3000/api/courses

[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "course1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "course2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "course3"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like a timestamp (2021/03/27 05:06:54)